# Accessing root files on Ubuntu Phone from my eOS based on Ubuntu.

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch, filesystem, touchscreen, phone

I'm wondering if its possible to access the root files on my Ubuntu Phone E5 from my computer. I know I can access them from the terminal on the phone but its not ideal using that touchscreen to explore. Is there a way to gain access to these files from my elementary os (freya, based on ubuntu distro)?

Thanks

Comment: Questions on elementary should be asked on [unix.se].

Comment: Okey I will place it there. Sorry, I am new to stack exchange and linux.

Comment: @muru: From my understanding questions on Ubuntu Phone are on topic, so I don't understand why this should be off-topic. Moreover, the procedure should be quite distro agnostic anyway...

Comment: @Bruni sure, questions on Ubuntu Phone are. But this, to me, seems to be more about elementary. Without seeing an answer, I don't know if the procedure is distro-agnostic or not.